# How to SELECT from any spreadsheet in Excel File using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, linq, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I'm using `OleDbDataAdapter` to extract `DataSet` from excel file, but I have problems with `SELECT` statement inside

```
DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
using (OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
     con.Open();
     OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Name of spreadsheet]", con);
     cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);
     con.Close();
}
```

If you see I have `"select * from [Name of spreadsheet]"`, but I need to get any spreadsheets, or for example 1st spreadsheet, but the name for this spreadsheet can be anything.

How to specify it? Is it any special characters like `"select * from [%]"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to know the name of the sheet to apply the select statement at it.
And you need to add the special char `$` at the end of the name.

Supposing you have a sheet named `MyFirstSheet` then you can select rows from it with

```
 OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [MyFirstSheet$]", con);
```

In case you don't know the names of your sheets you could call

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("Tables");
    string firstSheet = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    ...... work with the first sheet .....
}
```

This example should give you the name of the first sheet in the excel file (other sheets are available in the successive rows after the first)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Upvote and accept=) Will read about schemas in OleDbConnection=)